# How to choose sun_path using minix3 VM as server and Ubuntu as client? (Unix Domain Sockets)

Tags: c, linux, sockets, minix

So, I have created a socket using C programming. I created the server inside `/usr/src/server/pm` as *server.c* in Minix3 VM and the client under `/usr/Desktop` as *client.c* in the host OS which is an Ubuntu machine. I'm facing the problem of selecting the *sun_path* name for both files in `strcpy(name.sun_path, PATH)`. When I'm running both files in the host I just define a global variable, such as `#define SOCK_PATH "socket"` and use it as the second parameter in the strcpy function, and it works, but when I  put the server in the minix VM the client throws an error saying that there's no such file or directory. What do I have to put in sun_path for client and for server?

Comment: You put the path you want to create the socket at.

Comment: Do they have to be exactly the same on both files? @immibis

Comment: If they start with /, then yes. Otherwise, they're relative to the current directory, which might be different between the two programs.

Comment: Also, as far as I know, *Unix sockets only ever work on the same computer*, and *a VM pretends to be a different computer*, so you cannot use them between VMs. (However, I'm not familiar with Minix, and maybe a Minix VM is something different to what I'm thinking of)

Comment: @immibis is right. One cannot use unix domain sockets between VMs. You could use a daemon in each VM that communicate with each other using IP or some cross-VM protocol (some VM containers support special protocols between VMs), and act as an unix domain "bridge" between VMs, but that gets too complicated. Use an UDP socket instead.